# Best UI for picking a birthday?

Tags: datepicker

I'm designing a form where the user needs to pick her or his birthday — **just day and month**, not the year.

As it's just the day and the month, standard practices for date pickers don't necessarily apply, though some do.

[Nielsen and Norman](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/date-input/) recommend splitting up the fields and spelling out the month if possible. [UX movement](https://uxmovement.com/forms/bad-practices-on-birthdate-form-fields/) recommends using plain text fields, but that eliminates the possiblity of spelling out the month. There's also a question of whether to shift focus to the next field automatically — [Lukas Mathis](http://ignorethecode.net/blog/2016/06/28/violating_user_expectations/) recommends against it, but without it, there's an extra click when using two fields.

I should also mention that the UI should consist of standard elements only. I know there are great custom pickers [out there](https://uxdesign.cc/rethinking-the-date-picker-ui-99b9dcb303ad), but this project doesn't have the budget to create one for such a small feature.

Answer (score 2):

NN's suggestion of splitting up the month and date looks like the proper way to do it. Open text fields are prone to so much error, the root cause of all bad data. With open text fields, one needs all sorts of validations to make sure that the value is acceptable. With dropdowns for month and date, these issues will be completely eliminated. For filling in values in open fields such as these users need to keep the recommended format in mind all the time. The placeholder is never of much help either. If it is open text field, I recommend displaying the acceptable format beside the field label so that it is visible while entering the birthday.

Comment: One example of issues you'll encounter with free text (even with masked input) is whether you're entering day/month or month/day — an issue you won't have if you have a separate dropdown with month names.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need only two dropdowns, but you can control them in two ways:

1- **First way** is to start with a month field with three letters abbreviation for the month, followed with a drop box of days.

You will ask **Why month first?** Maybe you need to control the days depending on month selection so the days will differ between 29/30/31

Ex: **Jan. 31**

2- **Second way** if you need it to be fully manual, so you can start with a day dropdown counter of 31 days so you can pick the day. Then a dropdown of months, either month name or number.

Ex: **31st Jan.** or **31/01**

That's all if you don't look for complication.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate option for providing a different user experience (since we don't have any information about the target audience), what about allowing the user to use information like their star signs to narrow down the date and month and then let them select the exact value?

It would be a different experience but perhaps more suitable for people who are accustomed to this type of information, but it could be quite effective and more engaging if it does fit with the target audience you are catering for.